# How can I get service object from Unity container?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
IUnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
            
unityContainer.RegisterType<IMembershipService, MembershipService>();
unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IMappingEngine>(Mapper.Engine);
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new UnityControllerFactory(unityContainer));
```

How can I get Unity container? `ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory()` - not.
First i get unity container, from unity container i want get service using `Resolve`. Anybody can help?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Why would you do that? It's dependency injection anti-pattern. Just let the controller factory inject your dependencies via controller constructor or properties.

Comment: Just i want get service from ControllerBuilder.

Comment: for not to create a service object in controller.

Comment: To bind exception logger on WebActivator.Start. Nothing wrong here and not always anti pattern.

Comment: Sometimes you want to access container registered instances from static methods... There's a very good reason to require it.

Answer (score 2):

Add a static method (see GetConfiguredContainer):

```
public class UnityConfig
{
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    });

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the configured Unity container.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The generated unity container</returns>
    public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
    {
        return container.Value;
    }

    /// <summary>Registers the type mappings with the Unity container.</summary>
    /// <param name="container">The unity container to configure.</param>
    /// <remarks>There is no need to register concrete types such as controllers or API controllers (unless you want to
    /// change the defaults), as Unity allows resolving a concrete type even if it was not previously registered.</remarks>
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
        // container.LoadConfiguration();

        // Example
        container.RegisterType<IFileSystem, FileSystem>();
    }
}


var unity = new UnityConfig();
IUnityContainer unityContainer = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
```

Then you can use:

```
TypeThatYouWant instance = unityContainer.Resolve<TypeThatYouWant>();
```

If you do not have access to the UnityConfig because you have the project dependencies in an awkward state, just add another UnityConfig static class with a static property for your container inside the project you need access to it, fill it up and then that project can have reference too:

```
// Some other project
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }
}

var unity = new UnityConfig();
IUnityContainer unityContainer = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();

project.namespace.UnityConfig.Container = unityContainer;
```

*Apart from this, try aim for a design pattern that can make the most out of the class construct injection.*